# image animation jquery on hover

Tags: jquery, image, hover, jquery-animate

OK,

I want that when I hover the `<li>` elements containing the images, the image grows up (just like in google image thumbnail

```
<div>
    <ul class="images">
        <li><img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x100"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x100"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x100"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x100"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the thing is that if i just animate the li, the other pictures will move, and the design will be broken.

here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dellwolf/T23yM/) if needed... thank you

Comment: why would someone downvote my question ?

Comment: Dunno, just upvoted it. It was a decent question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *li* must be relatively positioned, and contain an absolutely positioned element inside it.
The *li* hover state will make this other element expand, but as they are 'position:absolute', it will not influence the other *li* positioning.

Like (pseudo-code):

```
li{width:150px; height:100px; position:relative}
li span{width:150px; height:100px; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; display:block}
li:hover span{width:200px; height:150px; top:-25px; left:-25px}
```

You can also change your img's `src` attribute to load tiny thumbnails and bigger detailed images on hover, via javascript.

If you need animation, just add [jQuery Animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) to that.

- [Fiddle on **pure css**](https://jsfiddle.net/seza/M4gVN/)

Comment: i did the same using jquery though (no pure css:) but i still have a probleme, the photo does the right animation, but even with a z-index:999999999999 there's still the image on the right of the hovered image visible..

Comment: it does something like that : [link](http://estellechevallier.com/img/fail-hover.png)

Comment: Does it happen with other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You can find here variety of [plug ins](http://designshack.net/?p=36895) for that.They are nice plugins

Comment: ... ok but if i want to do it by myself ?

Comment: all the css is avialable there.You can use that

Answer (score 0):

I think you need like this

See this is the simple psuedo code according to your requirement don't know exactly what is your need.

**jQuery Code**

```
$('.images img').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $(this).animate({width: '170px', height: '120px', top: '-=15px', left: '-=15px'}, 500);
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).animate({width: '150px', height: '100px', top: '+=15px', left: '+=15px'}, 500);
    }
});
```

[**See Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T23yM/3/)

Comment: thank you Dhaval Marthak, but it's not what i'm looking for. I want the image to get bigger and the other images not to move at all !

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").hover(function() {
    $("img").css({'height':'200px', 'width':'300px'});
});
```

Something like this, perhaps?

Answer (score -2):

i Finally found an easiest way to animate the image without jQuery, 
only with CSS3 transition :

```
img
{
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    -webkit-transition: max-width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
       -moz-transition: max-width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
          o-transition: max-width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
            transition: max-width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

img:hover
{
        width: 120%;
    height: 120%;
}
```